# Is this the correct way to use Bloc in flutter?

Tags: flutter, bloc

How to use Bloc in flutter. What is the best way to use it? to wrap the whole app with `blocprovider`?

```
runApp(
      RepositoryProvider(
          create: (context) => API(),
          child: MultiBlocProvider(
            providers: [
              BlocProvider<GlobalViewBloc>(
                lazy: false,
                create: (BuildContext context) => 
                        GlobalViewBloc(context.read<API>()),
              ),
              BlocProvider<CountryDetailViewBloc>(
                lazy: false,
                create: (BuildContext context) => 
                        CountryDetailViewBloc(context.read<API>()),
              ),
            ],
            child: MaterialApp(
              home:MyApp(),
            ),
          ),
      ));
```

Answer (score 0):

there are two ways of accessing bloc:

1 - global declaration

you declare a bloc variable inside your bloc and all widgets and whole app will have access to that variable. like this:

```
final bloc = YourBloc();
```

2 - using provider

in this declaration you have to define the provider in the highest widget which you want having the access to bloc and all of its children will have access to that bloc:

```
class WD extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final bloc = YourBlocProvider.of(context);
/....
    );
  }
}
```